# Viewing an already running application through ssh?

Tags: linux, x11-forwarding

So I have Ktorrent running all the time on my remote host, and I have to change some of the settings on it every once and a while that can't be changed through the web ui. So I was wondering if there was a way to have the applications gui show up on my local computer so that I can change the settings. Both computers are running the same version of Ubuntu, and I need the window that opens up to be the same instance of the application that is already running on my remote computer. Any one have any ideas on how to do all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this task including ForwardX11, xhost, and freeNX.

On your ubuntu machine running ktorrent edit the file /etc/ssh/ssh_config and add the following lines:

```
ForwardAgent yes
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Next, open /etc/ssh/sshd_config and make sure this line is present (if not add/change it):

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

Restart the SSH server and from the client machine run: `ssh -X user_name@server-ip`

After you're logged in run `gnome-session` or just `ktorrent`.

Other SSH options that may work:

- http://nixcraft.com/getting-started-tutorials/170-run-remote-x-applications-over-network-using-ssh.html
- http://www.torrent-invites.com/seedbox-tutorials/167614-easy-install-freenx-remote-desktop-ubuntu-10-04-server.html
- http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-8682.html

Alternatively `UltraVNC` and `x11vnc` both  offer "single window sharing".

`x11vnc` can be used with the `-id` or `-sid` option to share a single application window. To find the id of the application run the command `xwininfo` on the server and click the window or use the `-id pick` option to have x11vnc run xwininfo  remotely.

http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/x11vnc_opts.html#opt-id

http://forum.ultravnc.info/viewtopic.php?t=14780&sid=5e458a6faabff7ea00f050d88b0b69eb

Answer (score 1):

You can start the application in a different X server like `Xvnc`. You can then connect to this X server via various "Remote Desktop Clients" from any computer.

Comment: One can also share the default desktop over VNC with e.g. `x11vnc`. What one uses is case based.

Comment: I don't want to open another instance of the client. It has to be the one that is already running.

Comment: @Garethj94: Then look at `x11vnc` which shares an existing desktop session over VNC.

Comment: @DanielAndersson is it possible to just do that for one application in the desktop or would it be the entire desktop, also what ports would it be running on?

Answer (score 0):

Though the question was, how to display a running application, in this case, I would suggest you using some remote control plugin.

http://maketecheasier.com/remotely-control-ktorrent/2011/02/23

Comment: The web ui does not let you change the download location for the files. It can only be done from the application.